# How not to be able to select more than one row in ClistCtrl

Tags: windows, visual-c++, selection, clistctrl

I use ClistCtrl in my program and I want to have the program such that the user can only select one row at any time. How can I do it? Also if user selects multiple rows what the function "GetselectionMark" return?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First question: use the `LVS_SINGLESEL` window style.

Second question: GetSelectionMark() returns the index of the item currently focused if using the keyboard for item selection toggling per space key.

Comment: See the [documentation for `CListCtrl::Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa295592(v=vs.60).aspx).